# installing Mayavi with pip - no module named 'vtkOpenGLKitPython'

Tags: vtk, mayavi

I am trying to install mayavi via pip on my ubuntu 16.04 via shell. I am using python 3.6 via anaconda and already installed vtk and all other requirements but i get the above error when i try pip3 install mayavi or pip2 install mayavi.

Comment: pip install mayavi*

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you would not want to use the system version? Mayavi is packaged for ubuntu https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/mayavi2

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. But how can i install that package on my ubuntu?

Comment: did you try `sudo apt-get mayavi2` ?

Comment: Yes! it doesn't work. Gives the following error message:                              E: Invalid operation mayavi2

Comment: Oops, I forgot the "install" command for apt-get: `sudo apt-get install mayavi2`

Comment: Yes it works! Thank you.

Comment: Glad that it worked. You can mark my answer accepted, for others to be aware that the issue is solved. (and for my credits also :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Mayavi is packaged for ubuntu [packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/mayavi2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/mayavi2).

I suggest that you install with the command

```
sudo apt-get install mayavi2
```

instead, this will take care of installing a version that matches the vtk install on your system.

Answer (score 0):

> Try to rename libvtkOpenGLKitPython*.so file.

In my case it was:

```
cd /opt/conda/envs/pytorch-py3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vtk
cp libvtkOpenGLKitPython36D-8.1.so libvtkOpenGLKitPython.so
```

and, maybe one more error with **libxt6** file. Fix it:

```
apt install libxt6
```